# Difference between Authentication and Verification

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between authentication and verification? When would I use one over the other?

Dictionary definitions:

**verification**
ˌvɛrɪfɪˈkeɪʃ(ə)

*noun*: the process of establishing the truth, accuracy, or validity of something.

**authentication**
ɔːθɛntɪˈkeɪʃ(ə)

*noun*: authentication; plural noun: authentications
the process or action of proving or showing something to be true, genuine, or valid.

Comment: Note that if you're doing this in a computer/information security context, there may be very specific definitions for your domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Verification** and **authentication** are like **viewing** and **seeing**, i.e. the first refers  more to the process and the second refers more to the end state, originally in the mind of the human observer, but these days also in the formal state of an automated process. This is essentially what your dictionary definition is telling you.

An easy way to get the sense of each word is to use it in a different form and in a different context.  For example, if someone explained something to you, "I see" would be a natural response.  "I view" would sound bizarre, and even a stage comedian would have trouble pulling it off.

Here's an example:

> His story was completely unbelievable, but his papers seemed to be in order, so we gave him a fair chance.  The verification of his claimed itinerary was easy enough.  The photographs online were verified as having come from a phone once owned by someone of his name.  Verification of his passport took days, but in the end it too was declared authentic.
>
> So we published his account as a true story *authenticated by our editorial team.*  When the full story came out in the lawsuit a year later, we were dragged in as a third party, but ultimately found to be not liable.  Our *verification* had been extremely thorough by industry standards.  Still, I never saw the word *authentic* being much used in the period that followed, except when preceded by a very evasive "believed to be".

Comment: This makes sense now. I am building a digital platform which will automate the task of authenticating an individuals credentials. I was debating whether the platform should have verification or authentication in its name. After your analysis, authentication seems the correct word to use.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the *verbs*, the Oxford dictionary has this example for [verify](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verify):

> His conclusions have been verified by later experiments.

And for [authenticate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/authenticate) it has:

> They were invited to authenticate artefacts from the Italian
>   Renaissance.

So **verification** is proving that *facts* or *knowledge* are correct:

> We have verification of your identity.
>
> Please provide verification that you sent me the documents.

And **authentication** is proving that an *object* is real, is what it purports to be:

> Michelen has authenticated the food as genuine French cuisine.
>
> Sotheby's have authenticated the picture as an original Van Gogh.

Comment: But when considered as a process, both words are semantically the same?

Comment: No, they have different contexts.